# There is no login.keychain file in my High Sierra.Cant build titanium

Tags: macos, high-sierra, keychain

My KeychainAccess.app never creates the `login.keychain` file. So, I can't build titanium Application. If I create a new PC account there is no `login.keychain file`. If I reset default keychain there is also no `login.keychain` file.

```
appc ti build -K ${HOME}/Library/Keycahains/login.keychain
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong path for the login.keychain file.

You need to look in ~/Library/Keychains/ which means that your Titanium command becomes:

```
appc ti build -K ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```